# Why is my car not charging?

Tags: charging, fiat, palio

My fiat Palio 1.2 2006 model acted up on me in the middle of a freeway. I had just brought a brand new alternator and a battery, because they were giving me a tough time.

All was well unit today when the car flashed the oil and battery light and it suddenly switched off. I discovered that the oil cap is missing and that oil was splattered all over the engine. It probably got into the alternator as well because I don't think its charging. When I jump start the car then turn on the hazards it switches off.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: OIL CAP BEING SPECIFIC

Comment: Welcome to the site. This is a Q&A site where people answer when they can. As you have found, it is not the place to see urgent help. I have edited your question a little to make it more clear.

Comment: Fiats will fall to bits after about 100,000 Km .You will have to  replace every mechanical part one by one .Power steering rack sensor .Water pump .Windscreen wiper drive .Axle keys .Clutch .Ign leads .Radiator.Door remote lock              . Rear     Lamp socket wiring .  Front lamp socket connector    .Airbag wiring loom connector .Headlamps.  Front side lamps              .Aircon pipes .Aircon compressor seals .                   .Corroded blade fuses in ECU .LCD display on Radio .Cylinder head.Rocker cover gasket.Fuel injectors.Power steering electric servo              motor .No space

Answer (score 4):

**Check the oil level!! Most important; do not run the engine until you replace the oil and get a new oil cap.**

The oil warning light is there to let you know of a dangerous condition; there is not enough oil or oil pressure.

You said oil splattered out to the point the oil light came on, it is possible there is not enough oil left in the engine to safely operate it. This could possibly be why the engine will not stay running. Hopefully it has not been damaged internally from being run without oil.

As far as the alternator, the oil may have gotten on the belt causing it to slip, resulting in not charging. Alternately, it could have gotten into the alternator itself. This will require thorough cleaning and possibly a new belt.

To be safe, you should have the vehicle towed off the freeway (which you may have already done by now).

Answer (score 2):

I'm famous by forgetting to refit the oil cap, I think I have lost, easily 6 or 7 of those since I got into driving cars :) No big deal, although it surely adds a lot of cleaning time. Just refill the oil to proper level and put a new cap. I'm even thinking about having a cap with a string or chain, like old engines, that keeps the cap hanging so I won't loose it again.

That said...no charge after spraying oil:

Check alternator belt is not skidding: clean or change.
Alternator: remove from engine, do a good visual inspection for oil inside, clean the pulley, get WD40 or any other mild degreaser and apply to where the carbon brushes are. Also the contacts, terminals, etc.

Put all back together and give it a try. If no charge, then it may be the alternator got short circuited, probably its regulator "chip", however I tend to think it is more a cleaning job what's needed.